# Howto: Jquery Scrollto Action after Pageload instead Click?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Figured this needed a better explanation:

I have a navigation with some links:

```
<a id="home" href="/">Home</a>
<a id="screenshots" class="scroll_to_screenshots" href="#">Screenshots</a>
<a id="ask" class="scroll_to_container" href="/ask">Support</a>
```

And I have a js file with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".scroll_to_screenshots").click(function() {$.scrollTo($("#screenshots").position().top+10, 300)});
$(".scroll_to_container").click(function() {$.scrollTo($("#container").position().top-10, 300)});
});
```

Now for the screenshots it works fine: it scrolls down to the screenshots id. However the second one needs to load a page first, then scroll. Obviously that does not work (it scrolls down briefly and then the page loading kicks in. Can I change that action to -load page first, -scroll down?

And then obviously I have another problem, when I am on .../ask the first link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**simple**

you should use in the page load function :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), ToString(), "$.scrollTo($('#container').position().top-40, 300)", true);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not that advanced with jquery, how does it translate to my above code?

Comment: I think the above answer is for asp.net ajax.

Comment: oops..i meant asp.net..not sure why i put ajax :P ..anyways..i think simon is looking for pure js based solution

Answer (score 0):

put this in contact page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $.scrollTo($("#container").position().top-40, 300);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks James. Is there no way to define that in the js file itself? Like: Open page first, then scroll to.

Comment: I added my changes to the original post, you will probably find what I did wrong there.

Comment: why are u putting that function inside click event? since u need to run the code on pageload then thats where u need to put it in.  this is jquery pageload-> $(function(){ alert('jquery page load event');}) OR $(document).ready(function(){//code here});

Comment: Hm I think what I want doesn't work. The issue is the following: I have a navigation with links. Now some of the links just scroll to the id down the page, but one link goes to /contact first and should then scroll (I don't have access to the /contact html it seems.

Comment: if a different page is being loaded..and you want to 'scroll' on that page then js must reside on that page (contact)..unless you are loading the other pages through ajax

Comment: I've updated the text again on top to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you are not thinking it in right way..as soon as your new page starts to load..all the js code of last page is of no use!

Comment: Yes then I'll have to rethink the whole thing. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

So this does the trick. However if someone has a more refined, elegant answer I'm all ears.

```
// on the /example slug only
var fragment = 'example';

var url = window.location.href.split('/');

var last_item = url[url.length-2];
last_item = last_item.replace(/(\?|\#).*/, '');

if (last_item == fragment) {
    setTimeout(function() {$.scrollTo($("ul#posts").position().top, 300);}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your stuff here
});
```

Try using this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // Your stuff here
});
```

This will make the script wait until all elements on the page are loaded in before it scrolls.