# Howto: Check if on Page, if not Redirect and then Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, var

I am trying to get one last thing working:

I have a blog link in the main navigation and when you click it, it scrolls down to the blog. But when I'm on any other page, this logic obviously doesn't work. It should first consequently first go to the root page and then scroll. [I've got the opposite thing working here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498392/howto-jquery-scrollto-action-after-pageload-instead-click/7612578#7612578), but haven't quite gotten this task done yet.

Any help?

I am using scrollTo successfully like this:

```
$(".scroll_to_top").click(function() {$.scrollTo($("body").position().top, 300)});
```

The blog part however is not yet reacting:

```
if(window.location.hash === 'blog') {
    $.scrollTo($("#blog").position().top, 300);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Weboide, it's not a duplicate. I was able to hack this solution there together based on another post. Now I'm trying: root -> good, scroll. not root -> bad, go to root first, then scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a basic hash (`#`) at the end of the URL to automatically scroll the the element with the `id` specified in the hash (i.e. `http://example.com#blog`). That would be the simplest solution, with no need for Javascript.

If, however, the element you want to scroll to doesn't have an `id` that you can use (and you can't modify the HTML so that it does), or you want to animate the scroll rather than just jumping the the element in question, you could still use a hash in the URL and do something like the following:

```
//URL is http://example.com#blog

if(window.location.hash === 'blog'){
    //scroll
}
```

Finally, if you really hate the idea of putting a hash in the URL for some reason, you could intercept the click on the `<a>`, create a cookie, redirect to the desired page, and then have that page check for the existence of the cookie.

Comment: Thank you @maxedison, but it's not entirely what I want to do: the logic is: the blog (element) is only on the main page, so when I click blog on the main page, it will scroll down (that works flawlessly). But if I'm not on the main page, it should first go to site.com/ and then scroll to the blog element. Also check the inverted method I got working following the link in the post.

Comment: I don't see how the answer I provided fails to accomplish this. Let's assume on the main page you have the element <div id="blog">, and that's what you want to scroll to. If you are currently at site.com/about, the link to the main page with the blog element would be <a href="http://site.com#blog">. This would redirect to site.com, and then scroll down to the blog element. How does this not work?

Comment: yes, you're right @maxedison that SHOULD work. Thanks for opening my eyes. I've used the scrollTo plugin to do the scrolling so far, however it does not fire yet for the #blog part. I'll update the post, hope you can point out the problem.

Comment: You may need to put it inside a $(window).load() call because even when the DOM is ready, the size of the elements may not yet be determined. Also, I'm not even sure why you're using a plugin. jQuery's scrollTop() method should work just fine, and I think it offers better performance.